# Mathematica integration does not return value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I integrate the following, I get answer:

```
Integrate[(nor*x^ap*(1 - x)^bp*(1 - cp*x)*Exp[-t*al]), {x, 0.001, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {-1 < nor < 1, 0 < ap < 3, 0 < bp < 5, 0 < cp < 5, 
   0 < t < 2, 0 < al < 1}]
```

and the answer is

```
E^(-al t) nor ((1. Gamma[1 + ap] Gamma[1 + bp])/Gamma[2 + ap + bp] - (
   1. cp Gamma[2 + ap] Gamma[1 + bp])/Gamma[3 + ap + bp] + 
   0.001^ap (-((0.001 Hypergeometric2F1[1 + ap, -bp, 2 + ap, 0.001])/(
       1. + ap)) + (
      1.*10^-6 cp Hypergeometric2F1[2 + ap, -bp, 3 + ap, 0.001])/(
      2. + ap)))
```

But if I want to do this,

```
Integrate[(nor*x^ap*(1 - x)^bp*(1 - cp*x)*Exp[-t*al*(1 - x)]), {x, 
  0.001, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {-1 < nor < 1, 0 < ap < 3, 0 < bp < 5, 0 < cp < 5, 
   0 < t < 2, 0.5 < al < 1}]
```

it doesn't give an final expression. It gives:

```
Integrate[(nor*x^ap*(1 - x)^bp*(1 - cp*x)*Exp[-t*al*(1 - x)]), {x, 
  0.001, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {-1 < nor < 1, 0 < ap < 3, 0 < bp < 5, 0 < cp < 5, 
   0 < t < 2, 0.5 < al < 1}]
```

which is the same as the integral.
Could you please help me figuring out how to get answer for the second integral with additional (1-x) in the exponential?

Comment: It evaluates if you supply specific *integer values* for `ap` and `bp` but not for non-integer.  It also evaluates if you make the interval `{x,0,1}`.  Maybe take this to mathematica.stackexchange.com or even math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I need to do this integration numerically. I figured out, it is more of a mathematical issue of handling beta function